# Beautiful Soup: not grabbing correct information

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup to scrape the bold flower names and its corresponding picture link: http://www.all-my-favourite-flower-names.com/list-of-flower-names.html

I want to do this for not just the flowers beginning with "A", but have the **scraper** work for all of the other flowers you could attempt to get (flowers starting with "B", "C", "D", etc.).

***I was able to hack together something for some of the "A" flowers...***

```
for flower in soup.find_all('b'):  #Finds flower names and appends them to the flowers list
        flower = flower.string
        if (flower != None and flower[0] == "A"):
            flowers.append(flower.strip('.()'))
        
    for link in soup.find_all('img'):  #Finds 'src' in <img> tag and appends 'src' to the links list
        links.append(link['src'].strip('https://'))

    for stragler in soup.find_all('a'):  #Finds the only flower name that doesn't follow the pattern of the other names and inserts it into flowers list
        floss = stragler.string
        if floss != None and floss == "Ageratum houstonianum.":
            flowers.insert(3, floss)
```

The obvious problem with this is that it will most definitely break when anything changes. Could someone please give me a hand?

Comment: Consider using PyQuery instead of BFS, The development time is ridiculously faster. I load the page in web browser. Construct the element to be picked up using jQuery syntax. Simply paste the 'same' syntax in Python's PyQuery.. Boom.. the value comes to variable. 

Besides there are ways to grab the jQuery syntax just by hovering mouse on the element and copy jQuery path with little modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the flowers have been paginated across pages.
Something like this should help you loop through the different pages.
**CODE not tested**

```
import urllib2
test = {'A':'', 'B':'-B', 'XYZ': '-X-Y-Z'}
flower_list = []
for key, value in test.items():
     page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.all-my-favourite-flower-names.com/list-of-flower-names{0}.html'.format(
value)).read()
     soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
     # Now do your logic or every page, and probably save the flower names in a list.
```

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful!